# What's the difference between an .nbt and an .mca file?

Tags: minecraft-modding

What do I have to do if I want to save a .nbt file as .mca file? I got a byte array and all the data is OK. If I save the contents as a .nbt file I can open and view it with NBTExplorer. If I save it as .mca file NBTExplorer can't open it. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference, based on the Minecraft wiki documentation, appears to be that [`.nbt` is a binary format for storing arbitrary tree data](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_Format). The [Anvil format](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format) a type of region format, specifically for storing chunks of a Minecraft world.

An Anvil file might *contain* NBT formatted blobs of data describing individual aspects of the region, but the Anvil file itself is more a container of `.nbt` (and possible other data) than a a singular `.nbt` itself, and consequently it's very possible the `NBTExplorer` explorer tool simply isn't designed to open that kind of file.

It's also possible that despite your assertion, the data is not "ok" and may be malformed in such a way that it's parseable as a `.nbt` alone but when put within the structure of the `.mca` file, it causes some checksum or something to fail.

Comment: Is there a document which describes how a anvil file is structured?

Comment: I linked it in the question. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format (note that you have to read carefully, a key point there is that most of the format is unchanged from the region format, which is linked in the article but is also at http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Region_file_format).

Comment: My structure of the file is the same like described here http://wiki.vg/Map_Format

Comment: Is anvil still compressed by Zlib (RFC1950)? If I want do decompress an original .mca file I got an error...

Comment: I don't know, I don't work with Minecraft stuff I'm just going off the documentation there on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

After a long and difficult research I finally found a post which describes how the anvil is saved in .mca files.
Have fun!
https://web.archive.org/web/20150405111040/http://wiki.vg/User:Sprenger120